# How to perform $.each loop with limited number of itrations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on display various properties with their images and details, which are come from AJAX response. But the problem is, slider have a number of slides and each slides have 4 `li` .

And when i append my result `li` with slider, it will append all result `li` in that first slide.

So now i want to append these `li`(s) with only single slide and so on

**here is my slider code**

```
    <div class="work_carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">//here is first slide which have contains some dummy content
                    <ul class="thumbnails" id="work_property">
                        <li class="span3" >
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Property Name</h4>
                        <p>Property Description</p>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Property Name</h4>
                        <p>Property Description</p>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Property Name</h4>
                        <p>Property Description</p>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Property Name</h4>
                        <p>Property Description</p>

                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
              </div>
            <div class="item">//here is second slide which have contains some dummy content
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Property Name</h4>
                        <p>Property Description</p>

                            </div>

                        </li>
                        </ul></div>

        </div>

        <div class="control-box" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">                            
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>      
</div>
</div>
```

**Here is my AJAX Responce**

```
jQuery.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'<?php echo base_url("site/landing/get_work_places"); ?>',
           data:{ country_name:country },
           dataType: 'json', 

           success:function(data)
           {

                     var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);  

                     var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

               if (json=="")
               {

                      alert("no results found");
               }else
               {

                   $.each(json, function(key, data) 
                     {

                          var product_id=data.product_id;
                          var product_name=data.product_title;

                         var product_image=data.product_image;


                         $("#work_property").append('<li class="span3"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php echo base_url('rental'); ?>/'+product_id+'"><img src="'+product_image+'" alt=""></a></div><div class="caption"><h4>'+product_name+'</h4>  <p>Property Description</p></div></li>');



                      });
              }
           }
          });
```

**And Here is the reult slider with ajax response append**

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you want to say? Can you be more specific.

Comment: *"How to perform $.each loop with limited number of itrations?"* -- It's in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Read the last sentence before the **Examples**.

Comment: Hello @nikamanish, i just want to say that i try to append the resultant  li(s) with four li(s) in one single slide. the problem is that, it appended entire resultant li(2) in first slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `slice` and `wrapAll` to  wrap the 4 li's in the ul and the`.item` div after you append them to the page

```
$.each(json, function(key, data) {
  var product_id = data.product_id;
  var product_name = data.product_title;
  var product_image = data.product_image;
  $("#work_property").append('<li class="span3"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php echo base_url('
    rental '); ?>/' + product_id + '"><img src="' + product_image + '" alt=""></a></div><div class="caption"><h4>' + product_name + '</h4>  <p>Property Description</p></div></li>');
});

for (i = 0; i <= $('.span3').length / 4; i++) {
  $('.span3').slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4).wrapAll('<div class="item active"><ul class="thumbnails">');
}
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/qv9r7o2d/1/

Note: you may need to append the list items to the .carousel-inner div

```
$(".carousel-inner").append('<li class="span3"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php echo base_url('rental'); ?>/'+product_id+'"><img src="'+product_image+'" alt=""></a></div><div class="caption"><h4>'+product_name+'</h4>  <p>Property Description</p></div></li>');
```

Comment: Thanks @madalin , can you provide me where i can place your code in my logic. your guidance will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: after the $.each loop

Comment: not working.. :( it append entire resultant li in one single slide

Comment: how can be arrenge these resultant li(s) with 4 seprate li(s) in one single slide. for example first slide have first 4 li(s) then secong li have next 4 li(s) and so on..

Please guide me.. Thanks

Comment: did you append the code AFTER the $.each loop and change the append as in the answer?

Comment: yes. now it shows all resultant li(s) in first slide, means it covers entire web page :(

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. this error comes from our for loop which is placed just after $.each loop

Comment: my js is valid as you can see in the jsfiddle, you have some problem in you js , i hope you placed my js outside the each function

Comment: i placed your just after each function but insite AJAX success

can i going right?

Comment: it works with using previous one.. thanks buddy :)

but question arise in my mind is that, why this script execution takes too much time?

Comment: what do you mean by to much time?